# Const Overloading: Public-Private Lookup in C++ Class

Tags: c++

The following code does not compile, saying " error C2248: 'A::getMe' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'". Why? I am trying to call the public interface.

```
class B
{
};

class A
{
public:
    const B& getMe() const;
private:
    B& getMe(); 
};

int main()
{
A a;
const B& b = a.getMe();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Part of the problem which wasn't mentioned in other answers is that accessibility and visibility are independent concepts in C++.  The `B& A::getMe()` private member is visible in `main` even if it isn't accessible.  So in your call `a.getMe()` there are two overloaded members to consider, `B& A::getMe()` and `B const& A::getMe() const`.  As `a` is not `const` it is the private member which is selected.  Then you get an error because it isn't accessible.  If you hadn't the private non const member function, you would have the const member as the only possibility and it would have be called as a const member can be called on non const object.

Note that if visibility was conditioned to accessibility, you could have other kind of confusing behavior: you refactor a member, putting a call to a private member outside the class.  Now, the private member is no more accessible and so the call is to a different member which is public.  That silent change of behavior can lead to bugs hard to track.

In conclusion: whatever are the rule of your language, never overload with different accessibility, it leads to confusion.

Comment: "Never overload with different accessibility" except for constructors. It's perfectly reasonable to have a private copy constructor, even when that technically overloads a public default constructor.

Comment: @MSalters, when I overload the copy constructor as private, usually it is a work around: I want to suppress it, not to overload it.  As a proof: I don't provide an implementation :-)  But your point about the constructors is correct: as you can't get the some effects of a constructor without overloading them, you sometimes have no choice.  As for all general rules, there is bound to have exceptions; the notational convenience provided by operators may lead to others. In general obeying to published interfaces may leave you no better choice.

Answer (score 9):

In C++, you cannot overload on the return type. Overloading member functions based on their constness is no exception: You overload on the constness of the object the function is called on, not the return type.

To do what you want is a once-in-a-lifetime opportunity to use `const_cast` to *add* constness:

```
const B& b = const_cast<const A&>(a).getMe();
```

Of course, while this is strange and funny, it might be easier to read if you do it this way:

```
const A& const_a = a;
const B& b = const_a.getMe();
```

Comment: I'd be very interested in why this got downvoted. Care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 4):

a is not const in a.getMe(), so the compiler does not realise you are trying to use the const overload of the method.

```
A const a;
const B& b = a.getMe();
```

will work as you expect (except that A needs initialising).

Answer (score 3):

It is because to call the const method over the non const method, a should be const to prevent the compiler selecting the non const method.

Would it not be easier to call the private memeber function something else to avoid confusion of having two functions with the same names but differing access.

Comment: Not true: It is perfectly legal (and common) to call a const method on a non-const object. In this case, the confusion arises because there is also a non-const private version of the method, which the compiler decides to (try to) call.

Comment: good idea: probably should name the private function with suffix _i

Comment: @Martin B: That was what I meant. The answer has now been clarified. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.