# Why can't I access a public function that has a protected overload?

Tags: c++, overloading, protected

Given the code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}

    int foo() const { return 6; }
protected:
    int foo() { return 5; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compile error:

> 'Foo::foo' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Foo'

In actual usage, I'm trying to provide a function that returns a pointer to an object that the class is storing - modifiable for the members, and const for everyone else. I figured that if I say

```
const Item *i = foo.foo();
```

in a non-member function, the correct, const variant will be called. Somehow though, the compiler insists on accessing the non-const variant in the protected section. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: IIRC correctly the compiler pretends to be "dumb" when looking for the function to call and ignores visibility until the very end(where it then throws an error).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Const Overloading: Public-Private Lookup in C++ Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361618/const-overloading-public-private-lookup-in-c-class)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice, voted to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your variable is non-const, so the non-const overload of the function is selected. *After* overload resolution occurs, *then* accessibility is checked.

When const and non-const functions both exist, the const version is only called on const objects. Your `foo` variable is not const. You can *make* it const with a `const_cast` if you want:

```
const_cast<Foo const&>(foo).foo();
```

That's cumbersome to use, though. A better solution would be to just give the internal function a different name so it doesn't clash with the external API.

Answer (score 3):

For a non-`const` object, non-`const` function overload is chosen over the `const` function, if both are existing.

`foo` is of type `Foo` and not `const Foo`, that's why compiler chooses the `protected` version which is non-`const`.

In 3 ways the code will compile:

1. Either, Make `Foo::foo()` in `public`
2. Or, use `const Foo`, so that compiler chooses the const-correct
   version
3. Remove the non-`const` version