# Function Overloading different accessability but also different parameter

Tags: c++, interface, overloading, access-modifiers

Why is this not possible?

```
class DBHelper {
public:
    bool open(const char* filepath, const char* query = "");

private:
    bool open(const char* filepath);
}
```

If I want to access the function `open(filepath)` of my library from another class it won't compile, eventhough the compiler should take the public function with the default argument. I don't want the user of the library to have access to the private function. Of course, the user could simply call `open(filepath, "")`. However, this is not comfortable and doesn't make sense, since I specified a default value.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361837/5619057) states that both functions are visible. However, since access is denied, there should be only one choice for the compiler.

I thought it is a common style to have an interface function with default parameters and private functions which are implemented based on the input.

(The interface function should create the default layout of the database if a 'create query' is given, otherwise it should just try to open an already existing database)

Comment: If you called open with one argument from another member function of this class, which one should be chosen?

Comment: Rename private function?

Comment: Not sure which part of the linked post doesn't answer your question. But, if you really want a separate, private member, then maybe add a unique, second argument to that which is never used. Like `bool open(const char* filepath, double);`?

Comment: @Passerby it makes sense for a member function, but not for a non-member function. Jarod42: yes I know that this is an easy way, but my Question is, why this is not possible eventhough logically possible (since access let the compiler only choose one of them). Adrian: this post is about return type. But I have two function with different parameter and only one can be access from a non-member function.

Comment: I don't understand your reply. They are both member functions, and both are accessible to other member functions of this class. A call such as I described would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Simon Pio, why don't you call your `private` function, inside your `public` function if your `query` is empty ?

Comment: @SimonPio. This is not possible because overload resolution occurs before access checking, and this is a one-way through.

Comment: This is not possible because Stroustrup specifically decided to make it this way. *Changing `private` to `public` should never alter behaviour of a valid program, or make a valid program invalid*. That's the semantics he wants, hence the rules are what they are. Not because other rules are logically impossible, but because other rules would give undesirable semantics to the language.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. that was the answer I was looking for. Thank you for clarification.